# Avoid multiple if else

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization

I have the following scenario where,

A **`String arr[]`** as input which can have Integer values,null or empty as a string.
(e.g) `{"230",null,"6",""}`

Now,

**1.**  If a null or empty string present in first two entries of arr , it is an invalid scenario print nothing.

**2.** If a null or empty is present in last two entries of arr, and first two entries are not null and not empty print first two entries.

(e.g) If **arr[]** is {"2","77",null,"5"} output will be **2,77**.

**3.** If no entry in arr[] is neither null nor empty check if all entries are numeric. If not print nothing.

Now my code goes like this,

```
simple validation()
{
    onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty = false;

    if(//Check if first two params are null)
    {
        //"print nothing" and return
    }
    else if(check if third **or** fourth param is null)
    {
        onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty = true; // setting a boolean 
    }

    //Proceed to check empty string
    if(//Check if first two params are empty)
    {
        "print nothing" and return
    }
    else if(!onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty) //checking if null 
    {
        if(check if third **or** fourth param is empty)
        {
            onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty = true; // setting a boolean 
        }
    }

    //if all values are not null and not empty      
    //onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty  will be still false

    String result;

    if(onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty )
    {
        result = checkIfNumeric(0,1); // only first two entries
    }
    else
    {
        result = checkIfNumeric(0,arr[arr.length-1]); // for all entries
    }

    if(!result.equals("success"))
    {
        return and print nothing
    }

    if(onlyFirstTwoNotNullOrNotEmpty)
    {
        print only first two and return;
    }
    print all entries and return;
}
```

How can I better optimise this code with less if and else loops? Are there any possibilities via lambda expressions?

I don't want to use a third party API for null or Empty check of a string.

Comment: I would start by getting rid of the booleans and moving the actions you take when they are true into the blocks where you sett them. But it's a very unnatural problem, so you shouldn't be too concerned if the solution looks a bit unnatural as well.

Comment: @AndrewL With pseudocode like `if(//Check if first two param are empty){ "print nothing" and return`, this question would be very much off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: I did not see that, when I read 'how can I better optimize this code' I assumed they had finished code. My mistake @200_success

Comment: Code would be soooo much easier to read, if you indent it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is way more complicated than it needs to be:

You can do it without `else` clauses, if the code is in its own method, like your code appears to be.

Here it is, with comments:

```
private static void simpleValidation(String[] arr) {
    // Undefined Rule: If bad input, print nothing
    if (arr.length != 4)
        return;

    // 1: If a null or empty string present in first two entries of arr, it is a invalid scenario print nothing
    if (isNullOrEmpty(arr[0]) || isNullOrEmpty(arr[1]))
        return;

    // 2: If a null or empty is present in last two entries of arr, and first two entries are not null and not empty print first two entries.
    if (isNullOrEmpty(arr[2]) || isNullOrEmpty(arr[3])) {
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(arr[1]);
        return;
    }

    // 3: If no entry in arr[] is neither null nor empty check if all entries are numeric. If not print nothing.
    if (! isNumeric(arr[0]) || ! isNumeric(arr[1]) || ! isNumeric(arr[2]) || ! isNumeric(arr[3]))
        return;

    // Undefined Rule: Print all values
    System.out.println(arr[0]);
    System.out.println(arr[1]);
    System.out.println(arr[2]);
    System.out.println(arr[3]);
}
private static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String value) {
    return (value == null || value.isEmpty());
}
private static boolean isNumeric(String value) {
    return value.matches("\\d+");
}
```

If you want it with `else` clauses and no `return` statements, e.g. because there is more code after, it's this simple (using same two helper methods):

```
private static void simpleValidation(String[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 4 && ! isNullOrEmpty(arr[0]) && ! isNullOrEmpty(arr[1]))
        if (isNullOrEmpty(arr[2]) || isNullOrEmpty(arr[3]))
            System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n", arr[0], arr[1]);
        else if (isNumeric(arr[0]) && isNumeric(arr[1]) && isNumeric(arr[2]) && isNumeric(arr[3]))
            System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use switch statement for this. Loop through the value of your array and use switch statement instead of if-else.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html